# C# XML to POCO - same "xsi:type" cannot be used by different elements

Tags: c#, xml, .net-5

I have the following XML that needs to be deserialized into POCOs. Let us assume that for the time being the XML cannot be modified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query:QueryRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" 
    xmlns:rim="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0"
    xmlns:query="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    id="4ffb5281-179d-4578-adf2-39fd13ccc797"> 
    
    <rim:Slot name="SpecificationIdentifier">
        <rim:SlotValue xsi:type="rim:StringValueType">
            <rim:Value>sfts-edm:v1.0</rim:Value>
        </rim:SlotValue>
    </rim:Slot>
    <rim:Slot name="IssueDateTime">
        <rim:SlotValue xsi:type="rim:DateTimeValueType">
            <rim:Value>2022-05-19T17:08:10.872Z</rim:Value>
        </rim:SlotValue>
    </rim:Slot>
    <rim:Slot name="Procedure">
        <rim:SlotValue xsi:type="rim:InternationalStringValueType">
            <rim:Value>
                <rim:LocalizedString xml:lang="en"
                    value="Requesting a certificate"/>
            </rim:Value>
        </rim:SlotValue>
    </rim:Slot>
    <rim:Slot name="PossibilityForPreview">
        <rim:SlotValue xsi:type="rim:BooleanValueType">
            <rim:Value>false</rim:Value>
        </rim:SlotValue>
    </rim:Slot> 
    <rim:Slot name="ExplicitRequestGiven">
        <rim:SlotValue xsi:type="rim:BooleanValueType">
            <rim:Value>true</rim:Value>
        </rim:SlotValue>
    </rim:Slot>
    <rim:Slot name="Requirements">
        <rim:SlotValue xsi:type="rim:CollectionValueType" 
            collectionType="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:CollectionType:Set">
            <rim:Element xsi:type="rim:AnyValueType">
                <rim:Requirement>
                    <Identifier>315cfd75-6605-49c4-b0fe-799833b41099</Identifier>
                    <Name lang="en">Proof of Birth</Name>
                </rim:Requirement>
            </rim:Element>
        </rim:SlotValue>
    </rim:Slot>
    <rim:Slot name="EvidenceProvider">
        <rim:SlotValue xsi:type="rim:AnyValueType">
            <Agent>
                <Identifier schemeID="9930">DE73524311</Identifier>
                <Name>Civil Registration Office Berlin I</Name>
            </Agent>
        </rim:SlotValue>
    </rim:Slot>
    <query:ResponseOption returnType="LeafClassWithRepositoryItem"/>
    <query:Query queryDefinition="DocumentQuery">
        <rim:Slot name="NaturalPerson">
            <rim:SlotValue xsi:type="rim:AnyValueType">
                <Person>
                    <LevelOfAssurance>High</LevelOfAssurance>
                    <Identifier schemeID="eidas">DK/DE/123456</Identifier>
                    <FamilyName>Smith</FamilyName>
                    <GivenName>John</GivenName>
                    <DateOfBirth>1970-03-01</DateOfBirth>
                    <PlaceOfBirth>Hamburg, Germany</PlaceOfBirth>
                    <CurrentAddress>
                        <FullAddress>Dieter Wellhausen 71</FullAddress>
                        <AdminUnitLevel1>DE</AdminUnitLevel1>
                    </CurrentAddress>
                    <Gender>Male</Gender>
                </Person>
            </rim:SlotValue>
        </rim:Slot>
        <rim:Slot name="EvidenceRequest">
            <rim:SlotValue xsi:type="rim:AnyValueType">
                <DataServiceEvidenceType xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0">
                    <Identifier>2af27699-f131-4411-8fdb-9e8cd4e8bded</Identifier>
                    <EvidenceTypeClassification>Certificate</EvidenceTypeClassification>
                    <Title lang="en">Certificate of Birth</Title>
                </DataServiceEvidenceType>
            </rim:SlotValue>
        </rim:Slot>
    </query:Query>
</query:QueryRequest>
```

Using the above XML, I created the following classes using [XMLToCSharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/):

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace TestRequest2
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="SlotValue", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class SlotValue {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Value", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Value Value { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Element", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Element Element { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="collectionType")]
        public string CollectionType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Agent")]
        public Agent Agent { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Person")]
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="DataServiceEvidenceType", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public DataServiceEvidenceType DataServiceEvidenceType { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Slot", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Slot {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="SlotValue", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public SlotValue SlotValue { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="LocalizedString", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class LocalizedString {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="lang", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Value", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Value {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="LocalizedString", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public LocalizedString LocalizedString { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Name")]
    public class Name {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="lang")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Requirement", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Requirement {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Identifier")]
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Name")]
        public Name Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Element", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Element {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Requirement", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Requirement Requirement { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Identifier")]
    public class Identifier {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="schemeID")]
        public string SchemeID { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Agent")]
    public class Agent {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Identifier")]
        public Identifier Identifier { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="ResponseOption", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
    public class ResponseOption {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="returnType")]
        public string ReturnType { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="CurrentAddress")]
    public class CurrentAddress {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="FullAddress")]
        public string FullAddress { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="AdminUnitLevel1")]
        public string AdminUnitLevel1 { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Person")]
    public class Person {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="LevelOfAssurance")]
        public string LevelOfAssurance { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Identifier")]
        public Identifier Identifier { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="FamilyName")]
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="GivenName")]
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="DateOfBirth")]
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="PlaceOfBirth")]
        public string PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="CurrentAddress")]
        public CurrentAddress CurrentAddress { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Title", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Title {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="lang")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="DataServiceEvidenceType", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class DataServiceEvidenceType {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Identifier", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public string Identifier2 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="EvidenceTypeClassification", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public string EvidenceTypeClassification { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Title", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Title Title { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Query", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
    public class Query {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Slot", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public List<Slot> Slot { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="queryDefinition")]
        public string QueryDefinition { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="QueryRequest", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
    public class QueryRequest {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Slot", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public List<Slot> Slot { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="ResponseOption", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
        public ResponseOption ResponseOption { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Query", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
        public Query Query { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="query", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string _Query { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xsi", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmime", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xmime { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="rim", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Rim { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xlink", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xlink { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xml", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xml { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

}
```

When I attempted to deserialize, the following error was thrown:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (11, 4).
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified type was not recognized: name='StringValueType', namespace='urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0', at <SlotValue xmlns='urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0'>.
```

After some research, I came across [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885066/how-to-de-serialise-a-list-with-multiple-xsitype) which recommended that all the possible types of `xsi:type` should be defined as subclasses of `SlotValue` and included using the `[XmlInclude]` attribute. This seemed to bring some progress. I modified the class SlotValue to look like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="SlotValue", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(StringValueType))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(DateTimeValueType))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(InternationalStringValueType))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(BooleanValueType))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(CollectionValueType))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(AnyValueType))]
public class SlotValue {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Value", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public Value Value { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Element", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public Element Element { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="collectionType")]
    public string CollectionType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Agent")]
    public Agent Agent { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Person")]
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="DataServiceEvidenceType", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public DataServiceEvidenceType DataServiceEvidenceType { get; set; }

}
[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0", TypeName = "StringValueType")]
public class StringValueType : SlotValue {}

[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0", TypeName = "DateTimeValueType")]
public class DateTimeValueType : SlotValue {}

[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0", TypeName = "InternationalStringValueType")]
public class InternationalStringValueType : SlotValue {}

[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0", TypeName = "BooleanValueType")]
public class BooleanValueType : SlotValue {}

[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0", TypeName = "CollectionValueType")]
public class CollectionValueType : SlotValue {}

[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0", TypeName = "AnyValueType")]
public class AnyValueType : SlotValue {}
```

However, in doing so, the same exception would be thrown, this time on another line belonging to another element `Element`:

```
    Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (41, 5).
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified type was not recognized: name='AnyValueType', namespace='urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0', at <Element xmlns='urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0'>.
```

It seems that the above list of types is expected to be used by more than one XML Element. In this case, `AnyValueType` seems to be shared between `SlotValue` and `Element`. So far I have not been able to find a workaround for this.

My most recent attempt has included placing the `[XmlType]` attribute on top of `Element`, like so:

```
[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0", TypeName = "AnyValueType")]
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Element", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(AnyValueType))]
public class Element {
```

But this would conflict with the attributes placed on `SlotValue` as the following exception gets thrown if I were to do that:

```
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Types 'TestRequest.AnyValueType' and 'TestRequest.Element' both use the XML type name, 'AnyValueType', from namespace 'urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0'. Use XML attributes to
 specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @jdweng, I managed to find a solution to the problem.

Basically, I removed class `Element` and merged its properties (in this case only one - I removed `type` since it was redundant) into `AnyValueType`. Then, I simply replaced the call to `Element` in `CollectionValueType` to `AnyValueType`. To take @jdweng's example, it should look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication40
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QueryRequest));
            QueryRequest request = (QueryRequest)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlInclude(typeof(AnyValueType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(StringValueType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(InternationalStringValueType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(DateTimeValueType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(BooleanValueType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(CollectionValueType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Element))]
    
    public class SlotValue
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Agent")]
        public Agent Agent { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Person")]
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataServiceEvidenceType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public DataServiceEvidenceType DataServiceEvidenceType { get; set; }
    }
  
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "AnyValueType", Namespace  = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class AnyValueType : SlotValue
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Requirement", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Requirement Requirement { get; set; }
        
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public object Value { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DateTimeValueType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class DateTimeValueType : SlotValue
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public DateTime Value { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "StringValueType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class StringValueType : SlotValue
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Value  Value { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "InternationalStringValueType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class InternationalStringValueType : SlotValue
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Value  Value { get; set; }
 
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BooleanValueType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class BooleanValueType : SlotValue
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Boolean Value { get; set; }
 
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CollectionValueType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class CollectionValueType : SlotValue
    {
        [XmlElement("Element", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public AnyValueType Element { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Slot", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Slot
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SlotValue", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public SlotValue SlotValue { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "LocalizedString", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class LocalizedString
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Value
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LocalizedString", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public LocalizedString LocalizedString { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Name")]
    public class Name
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Requirement", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Requirement
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Identifier")]
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
        public Name Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Identifier")]
    public class Identifier
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "schemeID")]
        public string SchemeID { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Agent")]
    public class Agent
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Identifier")]
        public Identifier Identifier { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ResponseOption", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
    public class ResponseOption
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "returnType")]
        public string ReturnType { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CurrentAddress")]
    public class CurrentAddress
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FullAddress")]
        public string FullAddress { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AdminUnitLevel1")]
        public string AdminUnitLevel1 { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Person")]
    public class Person
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LevelOfAssurance")]
        public string LevelOfAssurance { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Identifier")]
        public Identifier Identifier { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FamilyName")]
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GivenName")]
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DateOfBirth")]
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PlaceOfBirth")]
        public string PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CurrentAddress")]
        public CurrentAddress CurrentAddress { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Title", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Title
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DataServiceEvidenceType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class DataServiceEvidenceType
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Identifier", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public string Identifier2 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "EvidenceTypeClassification", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public string EvidenceTypeClassification { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Title", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Title Title { get; set; }
     }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Query", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
    public class Query
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Slot", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public List<Slot> Slot { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "queryDefinition")]
        public string QueryDefinition { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "QueryRequest", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
    public class QueryRequest
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Slot", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public List<Slot> Slot { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ResponseOption", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
        public ResponseOption ResponseOption { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Query", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
        public Query Query { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "query", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string _Query { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The xsi:type attribute indicates an inherited class.  XML Serialize is not easy to debug.  I commented out the sections of your classes to isolate issue.  Then fixed issue and the added the commented code back into the classes.  Here are the changes I made

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication40
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QueryRequest));
            QueryRequest request = (QueryRequest)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlInclude(typeof(AnyValueType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(StringValueType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(InternationalStringValueType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(DateTimeValueType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(BooleanValueType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(CollectionValueType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Element))]
    
    public class SlotValue
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Agent")]
        public Agent Agent { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Person")]
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataServiceEvidenceType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public DataServiceEvidenceType DataServiceEvidenceType { get; set; }
    }
  
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "AnyValueType", Namespace  = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class AnyValueType : SlotValue
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public object Value { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DateTimeValueType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class DateTimeValueType : SlotValue
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public DateTime Value { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "StringValueType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class StringValueType : SlotValue
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Value  Value { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "InternationalStringValueType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class InternationalStringValueType : SlotValue
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Value  Value { get; set; }
 
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BooleanValueType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class BooleanValueType : SlotValue
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Boolean Value { get; set; }
 
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CollectionValueType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class CollectionValueType : SlotValue
    {
        //[XmlElement(ElementName = "Element", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        //public Element Element { get; set; }
 
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Slot", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Slot
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SlotValue", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public SlotValue SlotValue { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "LocalizedString", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class LocalizedString
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Value", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Value
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LocalizedString", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public LocalizedString LocalizedString { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Name")]
    public class Name
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Requirement", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Requirement
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Identifier")]
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
        public Name Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(AnyValueTypeElement))]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Element", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Element
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Requirement", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Requirement Requirement { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "AnyValueType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class AnyValueTypeElement : Element
    {
    }
   

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Identifier")]
    public class Identifier
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "schemeID")]
        public string SchemeID { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Agent")]
    public class Agent
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Identifier")]
        public Identifier Identifier { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ResponseOption", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
    public class ResponseOption
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "returnType")]
        public string ReturnType { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CurrentAddress")]
    public class CurrentAddress
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FullAddress")]
        public string FullAddress { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AdminUnitLevel1")]
        public string AdminUnitLevel1 { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Person")]
    public class Person
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LevelOfAssurance")]
        public string LevelOfAssurance { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Identifier")]
        public Identifier Identifier { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FamilyName")]
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GivenName")]
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DateOfBirth")]
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PlaceOfBirth")]
        public string PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CurrentAddress")]
        public CurrentAddress CurrentAddress { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Title", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class Title
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DataServiceEvidenceType", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
    public class DataServiceEvidenceType
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Identifier", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public string Identifier2 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "EvidenceTypeClassification", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public string EvidenceTypeClassification { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Title", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public Title Title { get; set; }
     }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Query", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
    public class Query
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Slot", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public List<Slot> Slot { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "queryDefinition")]
        public string QueryDefinition { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "QueryRequest", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
    public class QueryRequest
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Slot", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0")]
        public List<Slot> Slot { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ResponseOption", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
        public ResponseOption ResponseOption { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Query", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:4.0")]
        public Query Query { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "query", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string _Query { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The closest I have gotten to it working is having `StringValueType` inherit from `SlotValue`, and putting `[XmInclude(typeof(StringValueType))]` on `SlotValue` (essentially the opposite of what you did). This, in turn, creates the problem of having the type value classes being derivable only from `SlotValue`, so other classes like `Element` cannot make use of `AnyValueType` as it is a subclass of `SlotValue`.

Comment: Are you using the posted xml?  Are you using my changes withoout modifications? It worked with posted xml.  Before I modified code I got two errors 1) Around line 10 in xml :  <rim:SlotValue xsi:type="rim:StringValueType">2) Around line 60 in xml:  <rim:SlotValue xsi:type="rim:AnyValueType">

Comment: I followed all of your instructions and it still did not work. The error I kept getting was `System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (11, 4).
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified type was not recognized: name='StringValueType', namespace='urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0', at <SlotValue xmlns='urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:4.0'>.`

Comment: I updated code and is working except Element tag which I have commented out.  Thre is an issue with xml line 41 due to xsi:type="rim:AnyValueType" being defined in  both Element and SlotValue.  I'm going to try later with different version of Net.

Comment: I have been experimeting with making `Element` in `CollectionValueType` an array. Using `[XmlArray]`, I managed to get the deserialisation to not throw any exceptions, but the array of Element so far is empty. Perhaps this can be a potential way forward.

Comment: Identifier and Name does not have a namespace so use the default namespace in the element DataServiceEvidenceType.